# Run Application with more than one arguments VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to run an application with two arguments and wait for it to close. I'm confusing how to do it as long as there is spaces between arguments.

I want to do something like this:

```
App.Run ("Target.exe",/s /n,True)
```

True means wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the args in your string:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "target.exe /s /n", 1, True
End With
```

If you need to specify the full path (with spaces) to your EXE, things get a little trickier:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run Chr(34) & "c:\some folder\target.exe" & Chr(34) & " /s /n", 1, True
End With
```

Comment: is it working with msi installers? I mean does Vb Script Support msi besides exe files?

Comment: Yes. `Run` _shells_ the file. In other words, it launches the file using the file association established in Windows. If you can double-click the file in Windows and have it work, it should work using `Run`.

Comment: what the number "1" means in your code? does it refers to windows state? Can I just Remove it? something like this:  .Run "target.exe /s /n",, True

Comment: Yes, you can remove it. It's optional. It specifies the window style and `1` indicates a normal, visible, activated window, which should be the default. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank You Bond, it is a long time that you are helping me with VBScript ;) You're Really a Pro Scriptor...